# Splitting a list by another list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists one which is comprised of groups

```
['grp1', 'grp1', 'grp2', 'grp2', 'grp3', 'grp3']
```

And a second list that has the data I want to split into different lists

```
[1, 2, 1, 0, 10, 50]
```

I want to split the second list into 3 lists of

```
[1,2] [1,0] and [10,50]
```

The actual lists are much longer, with the original list not always having the same number for each group. However the list with groups is always in order ie grp1 will always be together and before grp2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the unique list from your original list, count its len (to create the chunks of the later list)

```
x = ['grp1', 'grp1', 'grp2', 'grp2', 'grp3', 'grp3']
y = [1, 2, 1, 0, 10, 50]


def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))


x_set = set(x)
n = len(x_set)
  
print(list(split(y, n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ask is to split second list into groups of two, you can use this

```
list2=[1,2,1,0,10,50]
# Considering list2 contains even no of items, else the last element will be single
modified_list2 = [ list2[i:i+2] for i in range(0,(len(list2)),2)]
# prints [[1, 2], [1, 0], [10, 50]]
print(modified_list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to split the second list depending on the number of times the groups appear in the first list? If so, I'd count the occurrences and use that to split them up.

```
from collections import Counter

ls = list(Counter(a).values())
remaining = b
out = []
for i in range(len(ls)):
    tup = remaining[:ls[i]]
    remaining = remaining[ls[i]:]
    out = out + [tup]
print(out)
```